# Mocking django Form cleaned_data field

Tags: python, django, pytest, magicmock

I have a simple django form like this:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

My view uses it like this:

```
def my_view(request):
  form = ContactForm(request.POST)
  if form.is_valid():
    data = form.cleaned_data

  ...
```

I want to test my view and don't care about what the form actually does. This is what my test looks like so far

```
@patch.object(ContactForm, 'is_valid')
def test_my_view(mock_is_valid):
  is_valid.return_value = True

  ...
  assert response.status_code == 201
```

However, this doesn't work because `form.cleaned_data` is not set until `form.is_valid()` is called. How do I mock out the `form.cleaned_data` attribute if it doesn't exist in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

You can mock the whole form class instead of just one method:

```
@patch('myapp.views.ContactForm')
def test_my_view(mock_form_class):
    mock_form_class.return_value.is_valid = True
    mock_form_class.return_value.cleaned_data = {}
    ...
    assert response.status_code == 201
```

Where `myapp.views` needs to be replaced with the dotted path to your app's `views` module. It assumes that you are importing the `ContactForm` into that module, e.g., with `from .forms import ContactForm`.